# Apache making the session time out longer

Tags: php, apache, configuration

I already altered my php.ini in Apache to have these settings:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.cache_expire = 1500
```

But my sessions are not that long.  The problem is that I am not certain which settings would "do the trick"

Ideally I am looking for the right configuration to have the session last 12 hours.  Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

do you also have set session.cookie_lifetime = 0 ?
and maybe somewhere in your scripts or some included scripts the session lifetime is set to another value?

The default "0" value means that the cookie stays alive until the browser is closed.  This is also the default value, if not set in php.ini.
Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Comment: But my application isn't implicitly using cookies.  Do I still need that setting? And why should it be 0? Or should I change it from 0 to something else?

Comment: Cookies are used to store a small session identifier, because HTML is stateless. This way Apache can request the cookie and if that cookie is available and still valid and it has a session ID that is still valid it can continue the session.

Answer (score 3):

session.gc_maxlifetime is measured in seconds, so your setting of 1440 will expire after 24 minutes. (see: http://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime)

For  12 hour session I believe you need:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 43200
session.cache_expire = 720
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

```
session.cookie_lifetime x
```

Where x is the lifetime in seconds

Also, if you are on a shared host, make sure the session data under /tmp is not removed by the host with some sort of clean script. Some hosts clear /tmp every 10 minutes.